# How to prove the tightness of Markov's bound?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Show that Markov's inequality is as tight as it possible. Given a positive integer $k$, describe a random variable $X$ that assumes only non-negative values:

$$\Pr[X \geq k E[X] ] = 1/k.$$

Using Markov's bound, we can show at most $1/k$. But how to show equality?! My question to be exact what is the idea to prove the tightness of this bound!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider a random variable $X$ which takes the value $1$ with probability $1/k$ and $0$ with probability $1-1/k$.

In this way, $\mathbb E\left[X\right]=\mathbb P(X=1)\cdot 1+\mathbb P(X=0)\cdot 0=1/k$ hence
$$
\mathbb P\left(X\geqslant k\mathbb E[X]\right)=\mathbb P\left(X\geqslant k\frac 1k\right)=\mathbb P(X\geqslant 1)=1/k.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helps me. I understand that "you give example" to show that it is tight so there is "no proof" as I understand. Also, I understand that when expected value is 1, then we have a tight bound for Markov's bound. So, thank you, I was thinking that there might be a proof.

Comment: @ArundoDonax You are right.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I believe X should take the value "k" not "1", with probability 1/k.

Comment: @Toastgeraet Looking at your suggestion, I get the deriviations:
pr[X = k] = $\frac{1}{k}, pr[X = 0] = 1 - \frac{1}{k} $, so the expectation of $X$ becomes $k$ since $k * \frac{1}{k} = k$. Then you should have $Pr[X \geq k^{2}] = \frac{1}{k}$ which is not true, infact $Pr[X \geq k^{2}] = 0$.

Comment: the expectation becomes 1 and not k. @Toastgeraet is right in saying the value should be 'k'. But hey, we can take the value of k=1 and this holds true.

Comment: @GadaaDhaariGeek Why is the expectation equal to one?