# Proving Tightness of Markov's Inequality for Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

For any value of $t \geq 1$, construct a non-negative random variable $X$ where $Pr[X \geq tE[X]] = \frac{1}{t}$. This shows that the Markov bound is tight. If we parameterize a discrete random variable by $t$ to get two values $\{0, t\}$ where $Pr[t] = \frac{1}{t^2}$ and $Pr[0] = 1 - \frac{1}{t^2}$ then we have proven the equation above. My question is **how** do you prove this? Working out the algebra, the equation holds, but how would you show your work?

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434241/how-to-prove-the-tightness-of-markovs-bound) here addresses the issue, but the random variable is different and the answer is essentially "no proof" which I am finding hard to believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to think of this as a counter-example: You are providing a counter-example to the statement that the Markov Inequality is *not* tight, e.g. the exists a $t \geq 1$ such that $Pr[X > tE[X]] = \frac{1}{t}$ for all non-negative random variables $X$.

Counter-examples can take a lot of thinking to produce, but often lead to very short proofs, since there is no requirement to show the thought process that lead you to discover the counter-example. However, providing this thought process can often be very enlightening for the reader.

In this case, my intuition would be that inequalities often attain equality at "extremes". Think of the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality where equality is attained when all variables are equal, or the fact that a bounded convex function attains its maximum at a boundary point. In this case the "extreme" is that all probability mass is distributed at the end-points of an interval $[0,s]$. You can also see that due to linearity of expectation, that you can assume without loss of generality that the interval endpoints can be 0 and 1.
Now you can parameterise all distribution on two values ${0,1}$ by the probability $Pr[1]=p$ and see if a particular choice of $p$ will lead to equality in the Markov Inequality.